# Difference between hardware time and system time

Tags: linux

I'd like to know the difference between Linux "hardware time" and "system time".

What time does the computer use from the point of view of a process querying it ?
Is it hardware or system time?

Comment: It would be helpful if you refined your question. There are so many relations between the two times, yet there are also so many differences. "Which time does the computer use?" It uses both for different purposes. "What is the difference?" Here you need to clarify the perspective. Do you mean, from the point of view of a process? Or from the system administrator's perspective? Or something else?

Comment: From the point of view of a process..

Answer (score 19):

The system time is maintained by the operating system, it is the one the processes will get when querying the date/time. Being stored in RAM, reading it is a fast operation.

The hardware time is maintained by a real clock powered by a battery. That means this clock persist a reboot. However, reading it implies performing a I/O operation which is more resource intensive than reading the system clock.

For that reason, the hardware clock is seldom used, mainly at boot time to set the system clock initial value, and then optionally to adjust/synchronize it either manually or through NTP.

Note that the hardware clock might be set to either the local time or UTC time while the system clock is always set on Unix/Linux systems to UTC time.

Comment: This is a very clear and concise answer. Obviously the question leaves open several possibilities as to what a proper response might be but the @jlliagre has intelligently chosen a very clear and concise response.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware time depends upon the BIOS ...the Bios battery controls it. So when system is shutdown, the timer is still ON .. (ie the hardware clock keeps running and keeping correct time)

```
 hwclock --show -->for hwd
 date            -->for sys
```

Comment: "so when a system shutdown its also work" -- what's that suppose to mean???

Comment: I guess that by 'so when a system shutdown its also work' you mean, hwclock still work when host is powered off (and battery still has power).